# timeout a user input in perl

Tags: perl, unix, timeout

I wanted to prompt for a user input and after a certain time , if no response , the script must exit . I had the code for this

```
eval {
        local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "timeout getting the input \n" };
        alarm 5;
        $answer = <STDIN>;
        alarm 0;
        chomp $answer;
    };
    if ($@) {
        #die $@ if $@ ne "timeout getting the input\n";
        $answer = 'A';
    }
```

The alarm timeout is working as expected , but I wanted an additional print statement after every second decrementing similar to a countdown (like for 10 sec say " 10 ...9 ..8 ..so on ) 
Could anyone please help how to get this feature embed along with the timeout.

Thanks

Comment: Just a note, [alarm won't interrupt STDIN on windows](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=perl+alarm+with+STDIN+on+windows)

Answer (score 6):

```
# disable output buffering
$| = 1;

my $answer;
eval {
        my $count = 10;
        local $SIG{ALRM} = sub {
          # print counter and set alaram again
          if (--$count) { print "$count\n"; alarm 1 } 
          # no more waiting
          else { die "timeout getting the input \n" }
        };
        # alarm every second
        alarm 1;
        $answer = <STDIN>;
        alarm 0;
        chomp $answer;
};
if ($@) {
        #die $@ if $@ ne "timeout getting the input\n";
        $answer = 'A';
}
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for the reply . Is it possible that instead of having $count printing as 10..9..8 so on , only one number printed i.e first 10 , then 10 is replaced by 9 ..so on every second.?

Comment: @user3304726 try `print "\r$count";`

Comment: @mpapec won't that appear to print 10, 90, 80, 70 ... etc ?

Comment: @RobEarl it will start printing with 9. In other cases spaces should trump rest of the line `print "\r$count   ";`